# Quiero obtener el ultimo id de la consulta insertada

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una consulta, que inserta clientes, lo que quiero es que cuando inserte el nuevo dato, automáticamente en ese método post tambien me devuelva el id de esa consulta.

La conexión a la bbdd es la siguiente

```
  public static function Conexion() :PDO{
    $conexion = null;
            try {
                    $conexion = new PDO(
                        'mysql:host='.HOST.
                        ';dbname='.DB.";charset=utf8",
                         USUARIO, 
                         CLAVE
                        );
                        //Configuramos pdo para que lance excepciones en casos de errores
                    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $e)  {
                   echo "No se ha podido conectar a la BBDD, causa PDOException: ".$e->getMessage();
                   
            }
    return $conexion;      
    }
```

La clase cliente que tiene la función insertar en la cual quiero que cuando inserte el dato, también me devuelva el ultimo id, es decir el de esa consulta es el siguiente.

```
 function insert($nombre, $apellido,  $dni, $email, $movil, $sexo, $id_mascota)
{
    try {
        $consultaInsertar = "INSERT INTO 
            clientes (nombre,apellido,dni,email,movil,sexo, id_mascota)
             VALUES (:nombre,:apellido,:dni,:email,:movil,:sexo, :id_mascota)";
        $conexion = new ConexionBD();
        $stmt = $conexion::Conexion()->prepare($consultaInsertar);
        $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);
        $stmt->bindParam(':apellido', $apellido);
        $stmt->bindParam(':movil', $movil);
        $stmt->bindParam(':dni', $dni);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':sexo', $sexo);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_mascota', $id_mascota);
        $stmt->execute();
        // Obtener el ID generado del cliente insertado
        $idCliente = $conexion::Conexion()->prepare("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")->fetchColumn();

    return $idCliente;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception("No se pudo insertar el registro en la tabla de clientes: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Luego tengo el método post

```
case 'POST':
    $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    if ($datos) {
        // Primero verificamos si el cliente ya existe en la base de datos
        $cliente_existente = $clientes->existeCliente($datos->dni);

        if ($cliente_existente) {
            // Si el cliente ya existe, devolvemos un error
            http_response_code(409);
            echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "El cliente ya existe en la base de datos"));
        } else {
            $nombre = $datos->nombre;
            $apellido = $datos->apellido;
            $movil = $datos->movil;
            $dni = $datos->dni;
            $email = $datos->email;
            $sexo = $datos->sexo;
            $id_mascota = $datos->id_mascota;
            $clienteId = $clientes->insert($nombre, $apellido, $dni, $email, $movil, $sexo, $id_mascota);
            if ($clienteId) {
                http_response_code(200);
                echo json_encode(array("idCliente" => $clienteId));
            } else {
                http_response_code(500);
                echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "No se pudo insertar el cliente en la base de datos"));
            }
        }
    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "Los datos enviados no son válidos"));
    }
    break;
```

La respuesta es el mensaje que sale del else de la funcion  no se pudo insertar el registro en la tabla de clientes, con un error 500

Comment: he probado con  $lastInsertId = $conexion::Conexion()->lastInsertId(); y me sale el mismo error

Comment: Veo un poco de lío y confusión en tu código. Por ejemplo, no entiendo por qué mandas en algún caso un código de error 500, cuando no lo es realmente. Si del otro lado hay un cliente que espera algo, lo que ese cliente necesita saber es si esa petición fue exitosa (código 200), aunque parte de ese éxito sea un **error de lógica**, como que la consulta falló, o no había conexión, etc. Trata de clarificar eso y no levantes una excepción en la parte de PDO, simplemente devuelve un array con un mensaje de error.